# Concatenate JSON in php with read Database

Tags: php, json

I read user from the database but I return json to ajax only return the last user because I cant concatenate the json encode.

```
  $myObj = new \stdClass();

while ($fila = $bd->fila()) {
    $myObj->NOMBRE = $fila["NOMBRE"];
    $myObj->ROLENAME = $fila["ROLENAME"];
    $myObj->IDUSER = $fila["IDUSER"];
    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
}



echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: build a "big" array inside the loop (= add new item $myObj), then at the very end json_encode() that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now overwriting `$myJson` in each iteration. We can also not "concatanate" two jsons (well, we could, but we shouldn't, cause it's laborious..).
 Better put everything in one array/object and `json_encode()` at the very end.

```
$myObj = new \stdClass();
$users = array();  // instantiate a new array
while ($fila = $bd->fila()) {
    $myObj->NOMBRE = $fila["NOMBRE"];
    $myObj->ROLENAME = $fila["ROLENAME"];
    $myObj->IDUSER = $fila["IDUSER"];
    // add objects to that array
    $users[] = $myObj;
}
// then at the end encode the whole thing to json:
echo json_encode($users);
```

Now here are some variants:
If you want everything that your db is returning in this items you could shorten that to:

```
$users = array();  // instantiate a new array
while ($fila = $bd->fila()) {
    // add the whole item (cast as Object) to that array
    $users[] = (Object) $fila;
}
// then at the end encode the whole thing to json:
echo json_encode($users);
```

If you don't care if the items are objects or arrays you could skip the casting and just add the array to the big array:

```
 $users[] = $fila;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to collect data to big array and then encode whole array. Also there's no reason for creating new StdObjects instead of usual arrays.

```
// define empty array
$result = [];
while ($fila = $bd->fila()) {
    // add to the array all needed elements one by one
    $result[] = [
        'NOMBRE' => $fila["NOMBRE"],
        'ROLENAME' => $fila["ROLENAME"],
        'IDUSER' => $fila["IDUSER"],
    ];
}
// encode whole result
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Your answer would be of greater quality if you explained your code.  It will be useful to new users that are learning.

Comment: @Nic3500 OK, no problem. I hope it has become more useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you concatenate it as array like this 
`$myJSON[] = $myObj;`
and then after the while
`echo json_encode($myJSON);`